# Merge two data structures based on common value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following situation with two objects that I have to merge based on value1 and I know the property is key1= namekey1 :

```
obja = [{ key1: value1; a : 1 ; b : 2}]
objb = [ {namekey1: value1; d : 3 ; c : 4}]
```

Desired result

```
objc = [{ key1: value1; a : 1 ; b : 2 ;d : 3 ; c : 4}]
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Will either of them ever have the same key names?  What happens if so?  Also have you tried anything that we can help you fix rather than suggesting a complete solution?  (Your examples aren't valid code either, by the way.  It's also unclear if you mean to have arrays involved or not, your code has them but your text doesn't)

Comment: I tried _.js map and extend but I only get the second object not the mixed one...maybe I misunderstooded the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a minimal example based on your knowledge on `key1= namekey1`.

However if may happen that both of these object have some common key.For that you need to check if there are same set of property name and add only those properties which are not in `obja`

```
var obja = [{ key1: 'value1', a : 1, b : 2}]
var objb = [ {namekey1: 'value1', d : 3, c : 4}]

if(obja[0].key1==objb[0].namekey1){
 obja[0].d = objb[0].d;
 obja[0].c = objb[0].c;
}
console.log(obja[0])
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/19bz75r7/)